# Can Moles be used to create a sealed class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moles, pex

I am trying to mock my Linq To SQL classes.

I have the following code:

```
IQueryable<User> vUser =
     (from aUser in _ctx.Users
      where aUser.UserName == userName
      select aUser);
```

Clearly while doing a unit test `_ctx.Users` is null.  I can mock `_ctx` (the data context), but `Users` is a [`Table<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx) and is sealed.  So this fails:

```
_ctx.Users = Table<User>();
```

Pex talks about being able to divert any method call via the use of [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/).

I see examples letting you override DateTime.Now(), but I can't see if this would help in my scenario.

Any one have experience with this?

Comment: Moles has been replaced by Fakes in VS 2012 and Fakes are Available for VS Premium- see http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2919309-provide

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim - Thats VS 2012 for those following along at home (not VS 2002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can.

See this post for more info.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/d73f730b-37df-40f9-8c62-afb76993fbbe/#86699ca1-70e6-4026-a1f9-4978e286d0a3